# Lifecycle event that can be used with blocks (threads) to notify when UIScrollView finishes "autolayouting" a UIImaveView?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, block, lifecycle

I have read through a large number of SO posts on this particular subject - there seem to be many people having issues using Autolayout with UIScrollView and UIImageView. Or perhaps there are just a large number of people (like myself!) new to iOS development that are going through tutorials happen to use these two objects for examples. Regardless, while I am guessing my issue is somehow RELATED to these other posts in some way, my issue is different in that I have been able to use these objects with autolayout exactly as I want, **until I tried to use blocks/threading!**

My understanding at this point of autolayout and controller lifecycle is that there is an "event" `viewDidLayoutSubviews` that is called when autolayout finishes "figuring out" where things on the page should be placed. I was/am using this to do some calculations on my UIImageView's `zoomScale` property to zoom the image so it fits the width of the space the UISCrollView provides.

```
- (void) viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

    CGRect scrollViewBounds = self.scrollView.bounds;

    CGFloat scrollAspectRatio = scrollViewBounds.size.width/scrollViewBounds.size.height;

    CGSize imageViewSize = self.imageView.image.size;
    CGFloat imageAspectRatio = imageViewSize.width/imageViewSize.height;

    if(imageAspectRatio < scrollAspectRatio){
        self.scrollView.zoomScale = scrollViewBounds.size.height/imageViewSize.height;
    }else{
        self.scrollView.zoomScale = scrollViewBounds.size.width/imageViewSize.width;
    }

}
```

This code worked wonderfully UNTIL I started loading the image Data in a different thread (see below). Now, my GUESS is that because my I'm calling this asynchronously `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is being fired/called before my image data actually comes back, or before it is fully loaded.

```
//This is called by an external controller and is what "kicks off" the entire process
- (void) setImageURL:(NSURL *)imageURL
{
    _imageURL = imageURL;
    [self setupImage];
}

//Required for zooming
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return self.imageView;
}

//Here is where the threading/block logic comes in play. If I literally just comment
//out the block/threading related code, everything works perfectly, other then the
//image loading "blocking" the interface
- (void) setupImage
{
    if(self.imageView){
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeZero;
        self.imageView.image = nil;

        NSURL *imageURL = self.imageURL;

        dispatch_queue_t imageFetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("image fetcher", NULL);
        dispatch_async(imageFetchQ, ^{
            NSData *imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:self.imageURL];
            UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
            if(self.imageURL == imageURL){
                if(image){
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        self.scrollView.contentSize = image.size;
                        self.imageView.image = image;
                        self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
                    });
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

My guess is that either there is a different callback that I should listening for (not sure if callback is the correct term), or I just need to somehow "wait" for a period of time to force my `setupImage` logic to run (i.e. wait an arbitrary amount of time in hopes that the autolayout has done it's thing and assigned proper values to bounds of UIScrollView and UIImageView, etc).

If it would be at all helpful, a running version of this code can be found here: https://github.com/develpr/PhotoViewr/tree/assignment-5 (note that if you actually download this you'd need to enter a Flickr API key in the FlickrAPIKey.h file for this to work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the solution to my problem was relatively simple and straight forward, and while the asynchronous call to load the image data was the "cause" of the problem, the only real problem was the order I was doing things.

The main issue seemed to be that `setupImage` was being called twice. Once I removed the call to `setupImage` things fell into place. I removed the call to viewDidLayoutSubviews which was ineffective, I believe by the asynchronous image loading (the viewDidLayoutSubviews was called prior to the image data and corresponding size being loaded).

Basically, I just needed to keep in mind the order that items were being executed (`NSLog` helped with this) and check the size/zoomScale values to see what they were being set to.